# Firefox Fonts via CDN with NGINX - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: firefox, nginx, fonts

Firefox does not allow cross domain fonts it seems.  In order to serve fonts from a domain other than the web page, the font files need to be served with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  I am currently acheiving this via NGINX like this.

```
location ~* .(ttf|woff|eot|otf)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        expires 8d;
}
```

This is working perfectly, however I was wanting to know what the proper value(s) for the header would be, if I did not want to use `*`.  Would be the subdomain I'm using for the CDN?  The domain for the site?  How would I specify multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be the doamin(s) from where you are requesting the resources.

Let's say you use the font for domain `http://example.com` then add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`. You can space-separate multiple origins.

In some browsers multiple domains cause issues. In that case you can programmatically read the `Origin` header of the response, check it against some whitelist and respond with the same value in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. IMO, the latter would be the *best practice*.

**Additional Note**

The value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header need to consist of scheme (e.g. http), domain (e.g. example.com) and port (only if it is not a default port).

[W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: The latter would be hard to implement, since once it goes out to the CDN, the CDN will only serve the file with the headers it received.  It won't check the origin server on each request.

Comment: Can you confirm that those full URLs need to be there?  With the `http` and not just the FQDN?